# NSTableView set target and action cause cell problems

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstableview, nstableviewcell

I want to detect click on cell in NSTableView
so I did:

```
tableView.target = self;
tableView.action = @selector(tableViewClicked:);
```

but I saw that another `@IBAction`'s that connected to the cell does not work.

what could be the problem?
thanks

Comment: Can you tell a bit more? Is the cell a cell view? Is `tableViewClicked:` not called? Is the action of the cell not called? To which control is the cell action connected?

Comment: @Willeke The cell has TextFields, i did connect action between the cell and the TextField, but the action is not called, even not stopped with breakpoint. What do you mean by `To which control is the cell action connected?`

Comment: I meant the text field control. Are the text fields editable?

Comment: @Willeke sure. it's works if I put in comment those lines

Comment: The action of the text fields only works when connected to the delegate of the table view.